# so how to add a int array to a spinner in android

Tags: java, android, spinner

so I have a int array and a spinner, I need the spinner to show the values of the int array. Being a novice, I am not sure how to add an int array to an arrayadapter or simpleadapter. I can use a list as well instead on an array, but it will always contain integer values.

```
mspin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
int[] items=new int[]{1,2,3,4};
ArrayAdapter<int[]> ad=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

//ad.add(items); // this cause some value to be displayed, possible the id of the item.

mspin.setAdapter(ad);
```

Thank you

Comment: Note it should be `ArrayAdapter<int>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use Integer, not int. This syntax works:

```
Integer[] items = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4};
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't that just work? Since the default `ArrayAdapter` implementation simply calls `.toString()` on each item. Perhaps you need to use an `Integer` instead (which is an object). Alternatively, you could implement your own custom adapter extending `ArrayAdapter` or moving to an array of strings to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting values from resources arrays then you should add double quotations around your integer items like this:

```
<array name="values">
    <item>"1"</item>
    <item>"2"</item>
    <item>"3"</item>
    <item>"4"</item>
    <item>"5"</item>
</array>
```

Then simply get values as a String array from resources and set them into adapter.

```
String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.values);
ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
mspin.setAdapter(ad);
```